# Angular components not binding ngModel after update from Angular 7 to Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, ngmodel

```
   Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

   <select class="form-control"
      id="ddlBinderNoCurrent"
      name="ddlBinderNoCurrent"
      [(ngModel)]="BinderNo"
      #ddlBinderNoCurrent="ngModel"
      (ngModelChange)="getReport()"
      required>
      <option value="0">All</option>
      <option *ngFor="let Data of dataForBinderNumberCurrent" [value]="Data.Binder_No"> 
      {{Data.Binder_No}}</option>
    </select>
```

already imported  FormsModule
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

```
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Are you sure you have imported the FormsModule into the module where this component is defined in?
Also: ngModel is part of template driven forms, no need for ReactiveFormsModule.
Also: the banana binding `[(ngModel)]` is a short-hand for `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`, so you effectively have `(ngModelChange)` declared twice.

Comment: Yes imported FormsModule  into root module .

Comment: and the component is also declared in the root module?